# Getting UnsupportedOperationException while pushing Docker image to Google Container Registry

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to push the Docker image to the GCR from the jenkins.

The script i tried so far.

```
stage('Push Docker image to gcr'){
                    script{
                         docker
                                .image('google/cloud-sdk')
                                .inside("--network=host  -e DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375 -u 0"){
                    withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'gcr- credentials', variable: 'File')]) {
                      sh '''
                        gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file ${File}
                        gcloud --quiet config set project order-status-api-0j7p
                        gcloud auth configure-docker
                        docker push gcr.io/order-status-api-0j7p/test-image:$BUILD_NUMBER
                        '''
                      }
                    }
                }
           }
```

But i am not understanding the exception thrown by the Jenkins.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.google.jenkins.plugins.googlecontainerregistryauth.GoogleContainerRegistryCredential.getDescriptor(GoogleContainerRegistryCredential.java:179)
    at com.google.jenkins.plugins.googlecontainerregistryauth.GoogleContainerRegistryCredential.getDescriptor(GoogleContainerRegistryCredential.java:66)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsNameProvider.name(CredentialsNameProvider.java:79)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsNameComparator.compare(CredentialsNameComparator.java:103)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsNameComparator.compare(CredentialsNameComparator.java:40)
    at java.util.TimSort.binarySort(TimSort.java:296)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:221)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512)
    at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1462)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:177)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(CredentialsProvider.java:563)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.findCredentialById(CredentialsProvider.java:906)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.findCredentialById(CredentialsProvider.java:850)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.MultiBinding.getCredentials(MultiBinding.java:144)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.impl.AbstractOnDiskBinding.bindSingle(AbstractOnDiskBinding.java:39)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.Binding.bind(Binding.java:150)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.impl.BindingStep$Execution2.doStart(BindingStep.java:135)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.GeneralNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$run$0(GeneralNonBlockingStepExecution.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Can somebody help me to solve this problem?

Comment: hey @PraveenkumarBeedanal , can you tell me where are you running your Jenkins (on [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-jenkins-for-distributed-builds-on-compute-engine) or on [Google Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/jenkins-on-kubernetes-engine-tutorial) or outside of Google Cloud) it seems that you are having permission issue?

Comment: @MethkalKhalawi Yes, actually i had a problem with service account permission. It means i forgot to add the `storage admin` role to my service account.

Comment: so you fixed it I understand?